# Can I have two Query Editor panels in pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

Can I have two different Query Editor panels in PGAdmin, side by side?

If not, is there another way of avoiding the pain point that's making me want two panels? That is:

When I'm building up a complex query, there's so much back-and forth that using the Scratch panel to swap queries gets cumbersome. It's like:

- Start with a basic query.
- Test run it.
- Add a where clause
- Cut-paste the query to the scratch panel
- Run a little SELECT to find a valid value to test the new where clause with.
- Move the query back from the scratch panel, plug in the testing value, retest.
- Add a JOIN clause, retest
- Add a WHERE clause using the new join
- Again copy the query over to the scratch panel
- Run another little select line to find a valid value to plug into the WHERE for testing.
- Copy the query back from the scratch panel, plug in the new value, run the test again.
- Repeat this iteration cycle until the query is where it needs to be.

And the steps where I just move the query being built over to the scratch panel and back over and over and over feels like a distraction and needless busy work. If I could just have two Query Editor panes, and run my little SELECTs to find values in the second panel, there's be one less little chore dragging me out of flow state.

Is there some way of getting a second Query Editor panel in pgAdmin?

Or is there some alternate development habit I could be using so I wouldn't feel the need for one?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken to opening a separate query tool.    SquirreL SQL (not that it matters).

One to write the real query, and one to investigate table names and column names etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found out that it's possible to have two windows side by side in pgAdmin.
A web search revealed [this thread](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2477595) on the postgrespro forum on how to do it:

1. Open two query windows
2. Move the mouse over the tab of one of them and drag the window to one side of the pgAdmin window
3. A shadow should indicate that the window will dock to that side. Drop the tab → the query tool windows should align side-by-side.